# How to add InfoPlist.strings into xcode project in script?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Unity to export xcode project, I need to localize app name.

I can manually add InfoPlist.strings in xcode, but I want to do it automatically by script.

I haven't find any way to do this, anybody help me?